# Load More with PHP prevent calling of en event handler twice on fast clicks?

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have this code, which allows me to make a "show more" button on Advanced Fields Pro repeater Elements in WordPress.

The problem is when I click fast twice(or more) on the buttons it shows me the fields, which are hidden also twice the (or more) time.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve it?

Code on WordPress Front end:

```
<div id="photo-gallery">
    <div class="row mt-5 mb-3">
        <?php
        if( have_rows('logos_der_externen_plattformen') ): 
            $total = count(get_field('logos_der_externen_plattformen'));
            $count = 0;
            $number = 5;                    
            while ( have_rows('logos_der_externen_plattformen') ) : the_row(); ?>                       
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 p-md-5 pr-2 pl-2 pb-5 pt-2 text-center" data-aos="fade-up">
<img data-src="<?php the_sub_field('logo'); ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('alternative_beschreibung_des_logos'); ?>" class="lazy img-fluid">  
</div>
                <?php
                if ($count == $number) {
                    // we've shown the number, break out of loop
                    break;
                } ?>                    
            <?php $count++; endwhile;
        else : endif;
        ?>
    </div>
    
    <div align="center" class="text-decoration-none">
    <a id="gallery-load-more" style="text-decoration:none;" href="javascript: my_repeater_show_more();" <?php if ($total < $count) { ?>  class="d-none" <?php } ?>><h7 id="title-bg"><span>und viele mehr...</span></h7></a></div>
</div>
```

```
    var my_repeater_field_post_id = <?php echo $post->ID; ?>;
    var my_repeater_field_offset = <?php echo $number + 1; ?>;
    var my_repeater_field_nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('my_repeater_field_nonce'); ?>';
    var my_repeater_ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    var my_repeater_more = true;
    
    function my_repeater_show_more() {
        
        // make ajax request
        jQuery.post(
            my_repeater_ajax_url, {
                // this is the AJAX action we set up in PHP
                'action': 'my_repeater_show_more',
                'post_id': my_repeater_field_post_id,
                'offset': my_repeater_field_offset,
                'nonce': my_repeater_field_nonce
            },
            function (json) {
                // add content to container
                // this ID must match the containter 
                // you want to append content to
                jQuery('#photo-gallery .row').append(json['content']);
                // update offset
                my_repeater_field_offset = json['offset'];
                // see if there is more, if not then hide the more link
                if (!json['more']) {
                    // this ID must match the id of the show more link
                    jQuery('#gallery-load-more').css('display', 'none');
                }
            },
            'json'
        );
    }
```

Backend:

```
/**
 * ACF Load More Repeater
*/

// add action for logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_my_repeater_show_more', 'my_repeater_show_more');
// add action for non logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_repeater_show_more', 'my_repeater_show_more');

function my_repeater_show_more() {
    // validate the nonce
    if (!isset($_POST['nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'my_repeater_field_nonce')) {
        exit;
    }
    // make sure we have the other values
    if (!isset($_POST['post_id']) || !isset($_POST['offset'])) {
        return;
    }
    $show = 10; // how many more to show
    $start = $_POST['offset'];
    $end = $start+$show;
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    // use an object buffer to capture the html output
    // alternately you could create a varaible like $html
    // and add the content to this string, but I find
    // object buffers make the code easier to work with
    ob_start();
    if (have_rows('logos_der_externen_plattformen', $post_id)) {
        $total = count(get_field('logos_der_externen_plattformen', $post_id));
        $count = 0;
        while (have_rows('logos_der_externen_plattformen', $post_id)) {
            the_row();
            if ($count < $start) {
                // we have not gotten to where
                // we need to start showing
                // increment count and continue
                $count++;
                continue;
            }
            ?>
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 p-md-5 pr-2 pl-2 pb-5 pt-2 text-center" data-aos="fade-up">
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('logo'); ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('alternative_beschreibung_des_logos'); ?>" class="img-fluid">  
</div>
            <?php 
            $count++;
            if ($count == $end) {
                // we have shown the number, break out of loop
                break;
            }
        } // end while have rows
    } // end if have rows
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    // check to see if we have shown the last item
    $more = false;
    if ($total > $count) {
        $more = true;
    }
    // output our 3 values as a json encoded array
    echo json_encode(array('content' => $content, 'more' => $more, 'offset' => $end));
    exit;
} // end function my_repeater_show_more
```

This solution fork just fine for me:

```
document.getElementById("title-bg").onclick = function() { 
document.getElementById("title-bg").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you could solve this:

1. Create a wrapper function around your JAVASCRIPT implementation of `my_repeater_show_more`. When this function starts, set a variable that the request is in progress. Unset the variable when the request has completed and the fields have been loaded. Disable the button when the field is set. This way, while the fields are loading, the button cannot be clicked.
2. Wrap your JAVASCRIPT call to `my_repeater_show_more` in a debounce. This will prevent the function from firing until some minimum amount of time has passed between clicks. Doing so will prevent the function from firing twice if you double click quickly.

More information about writing a debounce in vanilla JS can be found on this [excellent blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually still can't resolve it. I disabled the button on click, but it still doesn't work :/ I've just added the JS, maybe you can help me?

Comment: In your JS file, add some `var my_repeater_show_more_loading = false;` At the beginning of the `my_repeater_show_more`, set that to true. Once you get to the end of the Ajax callback function, set it to false.

Then, have a check at the beginning of the function that, if that variable is already true, don't make a call to the server.